# What is the "right way" to express the use of OpenCL with CMake >= 3.14?

Tags: cmake, opencl

Years ago, before CMake 3, we would write:

```
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(my_app ${OPENCL_LIBRARY})
```

... but that's not idiomatic today. We use targets and target dependencies. But - what *are* these targets for OpenCL? What OpenCL target should `my_app` depend on?

I'm specifically interested in how thing stand with CMake 3.14 and earlier (in case things changed with CMake 3.8 or some other version.) if not -  any range of version would do.

Comment: Same? It didn't change? I only see the case differs in [FindOpenCL.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenCL.cmake#L30). that's not idiomatic today - why do you think that? Maybe you mean that you should link against `${OPENCL_LIBRARIES}` and do `target_include_directories(my_app PUBLIC ${OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})` instead?

Comment: @KamilCuk: It obviously changed.  But those should not be the commands. There should be an OpenCL target to declare a dependency on. What is it?

Comment: Looks like the more modern way of pulling OpenCL into your project would be to link to the now-defined *imported* target `OpenCL::OpenCL` (which should pull in the include directories also). This has been available since CMake 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should work today:

```
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_app OpenCL::OpenCL)
```

and that should take care of includes and link libraries.